# SAS proc transpose

Tags: sql, sas

нужна помощь, очень!
Есть данные:

**id   период    товар  группа товара    выручка**

123  201801    яблоки   фрукт      65 руб

123  201802    яблоки   фрукт      21 руб

124  201801    вишня  фрукт     10 руб

127  201803    морковь   овощи  9 руб

129  201803    картошка   овощи  4 руб

129  201801    картошка  овощи  1 руб
...

Нужно их свести в такой вид:

**id    Продукт   Группа        201801   201802   201803...**

123  яблоки     фрукт        65  руб     ...

124  вишни     фрукт        ...

127  морковь     овощи    ...

129  картошка    овощи ...

Comment: На **Stack Overflow на русском** вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Переводить стоило только текст вопроса, но имена полей не обязательно. Добавте ещё, что с даннымй должно случится и вашу попытку решения.